# Is askubuntu.com hosted on Ubuntu Server Edition?

Tags: discussion, server

I was just wondering whether or not askubuntu.com was hosted on Ubuntu Server? I tried searching for it but didnt find anything so I thought I would ask at meta.

Comment: This is definitely the right place to ask it!

Comment: Related, but not duplicated: [How would #1 Bug would be fixed if AskUbuntu uses a Windows Platform?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/489/how-would-1-bug-would-be-fixed-if-askubuntu-uses-a-windows-platform)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, far from it (as far as we know).

See [What Was Stack Overflow Built With?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/)

You may also be interested in [How would #1 Bug would be fixed if AskUbuntu uses a Windows Platform?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/489/how-would-1-bug-would-be-fixed-if-askubuntu-uses-a-windows-platfrom)

Answer (score 0):

And if you only want to use ubuntu, you could use https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu .