# Could Ask Ubuntu run on Ubuntu + Mono?

Tags: discussion, windows, server

> **Note from Oli**: I have split this question in two. It originally asked both the technical ability to migrate and whether or not Ask Ubuntu would move to an Ubuntu platform in the future.
>
> I've left [the technical discussion on the main site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32140/could-askubuntu-run-on-ubuntu-mono/32146) and this thread can be for discussing our migration.

Inspired by the [old Hacker News conversation](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1782975) about this webiste, I'm wondering:

**Does Canonical have any plans of helping to migrate Ask Ubuntu to Ubuntu + Mono?**

I'm just asking if it would be *possible* and if it is *planned* to run this site on an Ubuntu server.

Comment: There is some Ubuntu in their setup: http://blog.serverfault.com/post/stack-exchanges-architecture-in-bullet-points/

Comment: Particularly, I'm wondering if, for example, Canonical has any interest to donate and maintain an Ubuntu server for the role of "Web server", exclusively to host this site (so SO wouldn't worry about it messing up other sites), instead of having it hosted on one of SO's 12 Windows Server 2008 web servers.

Answer (score 16):

I in no way work for Stack Exchange and I anticipate Jeff Atwood will chime in - however, I doubt this will happen. There is a [similar discussion about this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/489/how-would-1-bug-would-be-fixed-if-askubuntu-uses-a-windows-platform) when the site first started. In the end this site works, it works rather well on the platform running it. We're no different or special compared to [Webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), or any of the other [Area 51 Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) - so moving us to an Ubuntu server 'just because' would be like moving the [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) site to an Apple server - just a laborious act that can only result in less than the current stellar stability and performance.

I'm not endorsing Microsoft as a solution - I'm endorsing Stack Exchange as a solution. I trust they will make sure the platform runs and runs as well as possible while staying online as long as possible. If that means running the servers on 1,300 Windows Symbian based cellphones then that's that. :)

Stack Exchange isn't Open Source, isn't running on Linux, and likely never will. However, Stack Exchange is a community - and it listens to its community. The tools that run the site aren't nearly as important as making sure the community (and by proxy the site) grow to become the authoritative Q&A site for Ubuntu related topics. That's where the SE team (and us) should and will be focusing time and effort.

Comment: Best. Answer. Ever.