# If Ask Ubuntu is the place I'm supposed to go to get help, why is every hit related to my answer closed with "this isn't the place, file a bug?"

Tags: discussion

Seriously. I'm running 12.04 and getting messages about /usr/bin/Xorg crashing. So I come over here, start searching... and every case I've found is closed with "this is not the right place per the FAQ".

Would it be that much of a difficulty to either a) offer a known solution or b) link to the bug so future searchers can check on it?

Answer (score 11):

This is due to a bug in the bug reporting tool sending you to Ask Ubuntu when it should have reported the bug to the bug tracker instead. This has been reported, and fix was committed. Soon, you should get an update via the update-manager that fixes it.

- [Why is Ask Ubuntu being linked to from Apport?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3017/why-is-ask-ubuntu-being-linked-to-from-apport)

[Bug link here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/apport/+bug/991602)

#### Some info you may find useful:

As such, Bugs are considered off-topic here. We are a Q&A system, that is aimed to be a comprehensive one-stop solution for users seeking support. And yes, Ask Ubuntu is the best place for free technical support on Ubuntu related issues, but that does not mean we deal with bugs. I understand that a user seeing the message directing him to Ask Ubuntu may not be aware of that. Launchpad is the right place for bugs.